# Media query workflow and standard practice?

Tags: css, workflow, media

I'm working on a responsive website, but 1 question always bother me is that should we always work from smaller screen size and move up to bigger screen or other way round?

For me I find it easier to work from bigger screen then reduce the browser screen and adjust it slowly. The reason I do this is because I can preserve my original pc screen's design much easier, if I work from smaller screen onwards, adjust it to original pc screen design would be difficult.

Is it better to work from bigger/smaller screen onwards? What is your opinion in terms of performance, loading speed, and coding difficulty?

Answer (score 0):

This goes far beyond just responsive layouts or even CSS. You should optimize anything based on the way it will be used most. If I were making a site that most users would want to use from their phone, then of course, I would start development with the mobile version first! My reasoning is that there tend to be some trade-offs (albeit minor) with how things degrade as the screen size becomes smaller. To make sure the tradeoffs favor the mobile version, it may be best to start there and work toward the desktop version. However, I have always found myself in situations where starting with the desktop size is most practical, then I reduce the screen size and re-style it to my liking with media queries - reduce screen size, restyle, etc. It sounds like that's the approach you are taking and that should be fine unless a project calls for more attention to mobile from the beginning as I said.

No matter what you choose, if you are writing sensible code, the performance will be fine and the code should be understandable.

Answer (score 0):

As m59 said, start with whatever device will be most used. A scenario that can benefit from the mobile to monitor workflow is when you create a new site from the ground up. This scenario leans more towards affecting design decisions because by starting mobile, you include all of the features and contents that are absolutely necessary for the user - the bare necessities . This way you filter out any filler that go into some desktop sites, making your design cleaner and the UI more user-friendly. Also, starting from mobile will allow you to explore and enhance your mobile UI development ability for the future, rather than just learning how to cram it all in.